# Good library for parameter injection/properties management

Tags: java, configuration, properties, dependency-injection, configuration-files

I have a [piece of code](https://gist.github.com/3868359) that I have been using to manage properties for a while now. My boss didn't like this solution on the ground that property management should be done by well-known libraries, like Spring/Guice. That's understandable, and I'm looking for alternatives, but I can't find one that gives me the features that I want (or maybe I don't know how to use them properly).

The features I'm looking for are:

1. SUPER easy to add new properties to a class during coding

   1. No need to touch constructor, add dedicated field or setters
   2. Uses Java code (as much as possible)
   3. Easy to add defaults. No need to edit property file if you just want make something quickly configurable and keep the code working

   Can use any types (can define conversion from String within the framework)

   Custom validation that are run at config load time for each properties

   1. E.g. check for existence for a file, check if defined conversion succeeds etc.

   Ability to inject parameters to final fields

   Ability to auto-generate property file TEMPLATE

   1. Especially ability to define description, preferably in Java code which is then written to the template

   Ability to update config at runtime, in a thread-safe manner

**Are there any library that gives me these features?**

**If I'm missing something and these can all be satisfied by Spring/Guice, are there any good resource online?**

[Example usage of my solution](https://gist.github.com/3868631)
[Sample of generated property file TEMPLATE (you copy and edit this)](https://gist.github.com/3868903)

Comment: Are there solid business requirements behind your feature requests? Configuration via properties and DI are pretty much standart, just pick a DI framework.

Comment: @aikox well yeah, I use all features extensively. If you can direct me to a DI framework that can provide most of the features here, I'm in.

Comment: I am not sure I get the workflow #5 is designed to support. What if I have modified the template, and want to add another setting? Is that generation only intended to be used once?

Comment: You want to be able to inject values into `final` fields, and update this config at runtime...why?

Comment: @meriton Nah, if you want to add another setting, you only edit the Java Code. The template will be auto generated out of that on every build (every edit on the template you made will be lost).

Comment: @DNA I want to inject SOME values into final fields, and others to be updatable at runtime.

Comment: ... and what use is a config file that is overwritten with every build?

Comment: @meriton The TEMPLATE is overwritten. Not the config file itself. You copy the TEMPLATE, then edit that.

Comment: ... and if you have a previous config file, you merge it with the new template by hand? Might as well add the new settings directly to the config file, no?

Comment: @meriton Imagine you have config file for tomcat 6. If I release tomcat 7, do you expect to reuse the old config file you had on your servers, without editing? I think not. (sorry maybe I don't understand your question correctly)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that generating new templates, and then manually modifying the config file to conform to the new template, is not more efficient then directly modifying the new config file, so the template generation does not seem that useful. But anyway, you know your requirements better than I. Was just intended as food for thought.

Comment: @meriton Sure, I appreciate the input :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No need to touch constructor, add dedicated field or setters

That is not the [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) pattern. You might substitute the resource locator pattern, but doing that well (in particular, in a way the retains testability) is not trivial: With a setter, I can easily reconfigure the class under test. If that class depends on a config file, will I write a separate config file whenever I need to change settings for the unit test? Will I mock the config class? Possible, but not exactly straighforward ...

> Ability to auto-generate property file TEMPLATE

As already pointed out in the comments, this doesn't seem very useful, as it can not migrate an old config file.

> Ability to update config at runtime, in a thread-safe manner

That, in general, requires support from the component being configured (for instance, changing a setting for thread pool size involves starting / stopping worker threads ...). In general, the only simple way to handle that is restarting the application ...

If you drop these requirements, Spring's [PropertyOverrideConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-overrideconfigurer) fits nicely.

Alternatively, if you run inside a servlet container, you could pepper your Spring config with [JNDI lookups](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee-jndi-lookup).

If you really want to generate templates, I don't know a ready-made solution. I might do something like:

```
class Configuration {

    int threadCount = 10;

    String secretKey;

    @Description("Number of workers. Default value is number of available cores.")
    int workerThreadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    /** Use default settings */
    Configuration() {

    }

    /** read the settings from the file */
    Configuration(Properties props) {
        for (String prop : props) {
            Field f = getClass().getField(prop);
            f.set(this, props.getValue(prop)); 
            // TODO: type conversion, 
            // e.g. with PropertyEditors, 
            // or Spring's ConversionService, 
            // or invoking the constructor that takes a single string argument, 
            // or ...
        }
    }

    void save() {
        for (Field f : getClass().getFields()) {
            // TODO save the setting
        }
    }
}
```

Writing the default configuration would be a simple as `new Configuration().save(file)`, or upgrading an existing configuration as simple as `new Configuration(file).save(file)'.

Unlike your approach, this approach is statically type safe, and doesn't clutter the code accessing the configuration settings with redundant type specifiers. That is, instead of

```
if(config.value(Prop.PROXY_ENABLED,Boolean.class)){
```

you could simply write

```
if (config.proxyEnabled) {
```

and because the field can be of type boolean (not Boolean), you don't even risk a NullPointerException here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it. Indeed, I had to have property files for each test I needed a different config, and I didn't like the fact that it wasn't statically type safe and verbose. This solution seems to be much better. Thanks!!!!